# NDSolve with Piecewise gives the incorrect answer randomly

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, numerics, version-9, discontinuity

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

`NDSolve` in Mathematica 9.0.0 (MacOS) is behaving strangely with a piecewise right hand side.  The following code (a simplified version of my real problem):

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
        Piecewise[{{2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5}, 
                   {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}}
        ], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
Print[x[1] /. sol[[1]]];
```

gives the correct answer of 0.5 about 50% of the time, but often returns -0.5 and -1 instead.  Rerunning it gives apparently random results.  It always gives the correct result in Mathematica 8.

Here's what I've figured out so far:

1. It apparently has something to do with the `Mod[t,1]`, because it works fine with just "t" in the `Piecewise`.  Unfortunately I'm looking at a piecewise periodic system (not just from t=0 to 1).
2. It's only the first segment of the solution from t=0 to t=0.5 that varies from run to run.
3. Using initial condition `x[10^-100]==0` fixes the problem, but this is an ugly hack.

Can anyone replicate this strange behavior, know what's behind it, or have a better suggested fix?

Comment: I get the same strange behavior.

Comment: Same here Win7-64 v9.0.1. In v8 no such thing indeed. I assume it's a bug and suggest you contact wolfram support.

Comment: I filed this as a bug. Thanks.

Comment: @ruebenko: Have you seen ChrisK's finding about the `"DiscontinuityProcessing"` method option? It probably might help to track down the bug somewhat faster...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, yes this seems to be an issue with the new in V9 discontinuity processing. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just being curious, have you tried to use a bigger range for t, say {t,0,2}? The fact that when you use a close approximation of your initial condition you fix the problem smells like it has to do something with the computational grid chosen by _NDSolve_ ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following a lead from Albert Retey, I found an `NDSolve` option that fixes this problem:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    Piecewise[{{2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5}, 
               {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}}
    ], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];
Print[x[1] /. sol[[1]]];
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not really an answer (the answer is of course that this is a bug), but it is too long for a comment and probably gives a hint where the problem is and how one can avoid it in other cases. The workaround is to define the piecewise function as an external definition only for numeric arguments. It looks like otherwise some invalid optimization with the symbolic expression is done:

```
ClearAll@rhs
rhs[t_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{
   {2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5},
   {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}
   }]

Table[
 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == rhs[t], x[0] == 0},
   x, {t, 0, 1}
   ];
 Plot[x[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> (x[1] /. sol[[1]]), 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All],
 {10}
 ]
```

I have tested this with Mathematica 9.0.1 on Windows 7 64bit. Unlike for `NIntegrate` there seems to not be a `Method` option with which one could switch off the symbolic optimization, at least I didn't find one. It might well be there, even if not documented and of course might be a better workaround...

Comment: Thanks for the idea of looking for a Method option.  On a hunch I tried adding `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`, which seems to do the trick.

Comment: @ChrisK: good find, and the name indicates a plausible source of errors for this case. I'm not sure whether you are familiar with the site: it is welcomed to give answers to your own questions and accept them. I would suggest you should do that in this case...

Answer (score 4):

Another possible fix to the bug is to use `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` to expand the `Piecewise` into a combination of `UnitStep`:

```
Table[NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 
      Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
       Piecewise[{{2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5}, {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}}], x[0] == 0}, 
    x, {t, 0, 1}][1], {100}] // Union
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: can we use "Piecewise" to define Piecewise Initial Condtions for Nsolve in MMA 12?

Comment: @a If you mean i.c. for a PDE, it's supported at least since _v8.0.4_. There exists a number of examples in this site, for example this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44795/1871

Answer (score 3):

Taking the OP's clue that starting at `x[10^-100] == 0` solves the problem, we can try explicitly setting the derivative value at `t == 0`. The following produces a consistent and correct result:

```
solME2 = First@ NDSolve[{
   x'[t] == Piecewise[{
      {2, t == 0},
      {2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5},
      {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}}],
   x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}]

ListLinePlot[x /. solME2, Mesh -> All]
```

As an aside, discontinuities are processed as events, and generally an event at the initial condition is problematic.  Even if this observation is related to the issue, it's is still far from explaining the lack of determinacy in the computation.  It's certainly a bug, and a full explanation may be elusive.

Note also that turning off discontinuity processing, either with the option `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}` or by using `?NumericQ`-protected function for the right-hand side, has its own issues:

```
sol10 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Piecewise[{
       {2, 0 <= Mod[t, 1] < 0.5},
       {-1, 0.5 <= Mod[t, 1] < 1}}],
    x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10},
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];
ListLinePlot[x /. sol10[[1]], Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The maximum step size is too large and the discontinuities are jumped over.  You should be prepared to manually intervene in such cases.

The OP's code also leaks variables of the form `sNNN` from `Unique["s"]`, like another recent question, [Generation of global variables when using NDSolveValue and Piecewise function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129583/generation-of-global-variables-when-using-ndsolvevalue-and-piecewise-function).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  Another time I ran into the "events at the initial conditions are problematic" is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123550/whenevent-applied-at-initial-time).  Also, that `ListLinePlot[x /. solME2, Mesh -> All]` trick is slick!