# WhenEvent applied at initial time

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

Can a time-based `WhenEvent` be triggered at the initial time within `NDSolve`?  As a minimal example, a pulse is to be applied every integer time `t`, but `NDSolve` skips the initial pulse at `t=0`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> x[t] + 1]},
  x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

One possible solution is to give the initial values just before `t=0`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[-$MachineEpsilon] == 0,
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> x[t] + 1]}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

but this leaves me slightly uneasy, because in general, the system will vary in the small time between `t=-$MachineEpsilon` and `t=0`.  Also `x[0]/.sol` yields `0.`  instead of `1.` even with this hack.

Is there a better way for such a time-based `WhenEvent` to be triggered at the initial time?

Comment: Similar to your approach you can create a separate `WhenEvent` : `WhenEvent[ t == $MachineEpsilon , .. ]`   Obviously for this example you could just set initial condition `x[0]=1`, you might want to come up with a not-so-trivial example.

Comment: I don't think so.  Unless you consider an initial condition an "event." :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could back up the initial condition so that `t == 0` becomes an event, or you could effectively have a discrete variable be a switch to "turn on" the ODE at `t == 0`:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[-0.5] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> x[t] + 1]}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A switch is a better way to keep the derivative `x'[t]` equal to zero until the first event:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == a[t] (1 + 2 x[t] - x[t]^2), x[-1/2] == 0, 
    a[-1/2] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> x[t] + 1], 
    WhenEvent[t == 0, a[t] -> 1]},
   x, {t, 0, 10}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {a}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: BTW, the simpler `NDSolve[{x'[t] == UnitStep[t] (1 + 2 x[t] - x[t]^2), x[-1/2] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> x[t] + 1]}, x, {t, 0, 10}]` fails to integrate, but I don't know why....

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple mind, so I wonder why you can't just code the initial impulse into the initial condition.

```
sol =
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], x[t] -> 1]},
    x, {t, 0, 3}][[1]];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's the obvious solution, but my real problem algorithmically generates the arguments for `NDSolve` within a function, so I'd have to parse out the user-supplied `WhenEvents` and then apply them to the user-supplied initial conditions.  That's why I'm looking for a simpler solution that applies the `WhenEvents` at the initial time.