# WhenEvent doesn't work as expected when the condition is satisfied in the first step

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, syntax, event-detection

I have noticed strange behavior of WhenEvent in the case where the body of WhenEvent is satisfied in the first step. For example,

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[
   y[x] > 1, {"StopIntegration"}]}, y, {x, 0, 
  10}]
```

integrates equation until x=10 (and not x=0). However, if I put

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[
   y[x] > 1 || (x > 2 && y[x] > 1), {"StopIntegration"}]}, y, {x, 0, 
  10}]
```

domain of integration will be 1.43*10^-14., while I would expect that domain is either 0 or 1. This is just an example of the more complicated ParametricNDSolve that I am working with. I would like to understand why is this happening and how could I require that if the body is satisfied in the first step, domain of integration becomes 0 or 1 or some other arbitrary number that I want.

Comment: (1) An "event" is a ***change*** in a condition from `False` to `True`.  If the condition starts in the `True` state, then it is not an event for it to remain true. (2) The conditions `y[x] > 1`, `y[x] == 1`, and `y[x] < 1` are each a special form of `y[x] == 1`. They each detect `y[x]` ***crossing*** the value `1` in one of three ways: increasing, either increasing or decreasing, or decreasing, respectively. This is in the docs under "Details and Options." Starting at the value `1`, `y[x]` cannot ***cross*** it.

Comment: thanks for this. but do you have any suggestion how to go around the issue i.e. I am working with family of ODEs with ParametricNDSolve and I would like to know for what parameter values WhenEvent condition is falsified from the start.

Comment: I should maybe explain one more point, but it does not apply here. "Increasing" means `y[x]` was below `1` before the step and `y[x]` was above `1` after the step. Similarly for "decreasing."  When the step (change in x) is negative, this definition of "increasing" means the slope (`y'[x]`) is *negative.* Likewise for "decreasing."

Comment: Maybe: `psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[sys, vars, params,...]; trial[paramvals_] := If[<test paramvals for WhenEvent condition>, $Failed, psol[paramvals]]` and test parameter settings by calling `trial[]` on them, which would call `psol` only when appropriate.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123550/whenevent-applied-at-initial-time

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this hack, but it is a way to make `>` mean *greater than* in `WhenEvent`:

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[
   EvenQ[0] && y[x] > 1,  (* A && B is a special form in which B is treated 
                             as a regular boolean propostion  *)
   {"StopIntegration"}]},
 y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

[There are several special-case forms of an event `A` that are described in the docs for `WhenEvent`.  It is not always treated strictly as a logical proposition. With the hack above, you lose the advantage of these special cases.]

Comment: For the event, you should be able to use any expression logically equivalent to `y[x] > 1` as long as it does not have the head `Greater` or `Less` (nor is one of the other special cases).  For instance, `Identity[y[x] > 1]` works.