# Mod[] does not work correctly in WhenEvent

Tags: event-detection

From the expression we know Mod[t,1]==0 and Sin[2 [Pi] t] > 0 are equivalent in WhenEvent. This can be seen from the results below.

```
{sol, data} = Reap@NDSolve[{x'[t] == Cos[t], x[0] == 0, WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, x, {t, 0, 20}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Red, Apply[Point, data]}]
{sol2, data2} = Reap@NDSolve[{y'[t] == Cos[t], y[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0, Sow[{t, y[t]}]]}, y, {t, 0, 20}]
Plot[y[t] /. sol2, {t, 0, 20}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Red, Apply[Point, data2]}]
```

But in my real case, Mod[]==0 does not work correctly.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
F0 = 14160; FREF = 40; C0 = 40*10^-6; C1 = 360*10^-6; C2 = 20*10^-6; R1 = 14000; R2 = 1000; IP = 60*10^-6; IN = 60*10^-6; KVCO = 300; DELAY = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{R1*C1*VC1'[t] + VC1[t] == VC0[t], R2*C2*VC2'[t] + VC2[t] == VC0[t], C0*VC0'[t] + C1*VC1'[t] + C2*VC2'[t] == ICP[t], \[Phi]'[t] == 2 \[Pi]*(KVCO*VC2[t] + F0)/360, VC0[0] == 0, VC1[0] == 0, VC2[0] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 0, ICP[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] > 0 && ICP[t] == 0, ICP[t] -> -IN], WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] > 0 && ICP[t] == IP, ICP[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[Mod[FREF*(t - DELAY), 1] == 0 && ICP[t] == 0 && t >= DELAY, ICP[t] -> IP], WhenEvent[Mod[FREF*(t - DELAY), 1] == 0 && ICP[t] == -IN && t >= DELAY, ICP[t] -> 0]}, {VC0, VC1, VC2, \[Phi]}, {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> ICP];
Plot[VC2[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 30}]
```

Now if I use Sin[]>0, it works pretty fine.

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{R1*C1*VC1'[t] + VC1[t] == VC0[t], R2*C2*VC2'[t] + VC2[t] == VC0[t], C0*VC0'[t] + C1*VC1'[t] + C2*VC2'[t] == ICP[t], \[Phi]'[t] == 2 \[Pi]*(KVCO*VC2[t] + F0)/360, VC0[0] == 0, VC1[0] == 0, VC2[0] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 0, ICP[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] > 0 && ICP[t] == 0, ICP[t] -> -IN], WhenEvent[Sin[\[Phi][t]] > 0 && ICP[t] == IP, ICP[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[Sin[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == 0 && t >= DELAY, ICP[t] -> IP], WhenEvent[Sin[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == -IN && t >= DELAY,ICP[t] -> 0]}, {VC0, VC1, VC2, \[Phi]}, {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> ICP];
Plot[VC2[t] /. sol2, {t, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: Can you boil this all down to a simpler case? For instance, can you at least reproduce the problem with just a single WhenEvent?

Comment: I suggest reading many posts about the peculiarities of `WhenEvent` on this site ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233889/whenevent-doesnt-work-as-expected-when-the-condition-is-satisfied-in-the-first), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent)). Try reordering the conditions and using a function with even crossing (`Mod[..., 2] < 1]`) instead of an odd one (`Mod[..., 1] == 0]`): `WhenEvent[t >= DELAY && ICP[t] == 0 && Mod[FREF*(t - DELAY), 1] == 0, ...]`

Comment: `NDSolve` uses a sequence of steps of the independent variable between its minimum and maximum values; it adaptively determines the step size. For an arbitrary step $x$, `Sin[x] > 0` is True for a wide range of values, but `Mod[x, 1] == 0` is True only when $x$ is near an integer within a small multiple of $MachineEpsilon. So unless the step size is small enough, `Mod[FREF*(t - DELAY), 1] == 0` never encountrers a value that returns True. On the other hand, `Sin[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)]  >  0` is True even when the step size is relatively large.

Comment: See [NumericalOperationsOnFunctions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnFunctions.html#8415).