# Problem with a periodic function and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, evaluation, piecewise

I have defined a periodic function $f(t)$ like this (Mathematica 11):

```
fTmp[t_ /; 0 <= t <= 2] := \[Piecewise] {
   {1, t <= 1},
   {0, t <= 2}
  }
f[t_] := fTmp[Mod[t, 2]]
```

This works fine, as can be seen from

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Plot of the function...]

But when I try to use this function in NDSolve, I get a weird error:

```
NDSolve[{a'[t] == f[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 5}]
... NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {2.71828 fTmp[2.18952]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t,a[t],NDSolve`s$49306[t]} = {2.18952,2.71828,1}.
```

As you can see, $fTmp(t)$ is called with an argument $t>2$, which of course never should happen.
Any ideas how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two alternatives:

- Remove the argument restriction so that `ff[t]` evaluates to `Piecewise[..]`, which allows the discontinuity processing phase to see `Piecewise` and set up the integration scheme properly.
- Use [`DiscreteVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteVariables.html) to code the function `f`.

Codes (OP's answer, `Piecewise`, `DiscreteVariables`):

```
Clear[f, fTmp];
fTmp[t_ /; 0 <= t <= 2] := \[Piecewise]{{1, t <= 1}, {0, t <= 2}};
f[t_] := fTmp[Mod[t, 2]];
{sol} = NDSolve[{a'[t] == f[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];

Clear[ff, ffTmp];
ffTmp[t_ (*/;0 <= t <= 2*)] := \[Piecewise]{{1, t <= 1}, {0, t <= 2}};
ff[t_] := ffTmp[Mod[t, 2]];
{sol2} = NDSolve[{a'[t] == ff[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 5}];

{sol3} = NDSolve[{a'[t] == fff[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1,
    fff[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, fff[t] -> 1 - fff[t]]},
   a, {t, 0, 5}, DiscreteVariables -> {fff}];
```

Comparison (time vs. steps and size of solution):  The first alternative is better than the OP's, and the last is better than the first.

```
ListPlot[Flatten[a["Grid"] /. sol], GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{ByteCount@sol, "bytes"}, " "],
 AxesLabel -> {"steps", "time"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[Flatten[a["Grid"] /. sol2], GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{ByteCount@sol2, "bytes"}, " "],
 AxesLabel -> {"steps", "time"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[Flatten[a["Grid"] /. sol3], GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{ByteCount@sol3, "bytes"}, " "], 
 AxesLabel -> {"steps", "time"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way for the given example is to use `DSolve` with the first alternative:

```
{sol4} = DSolve[{a'[t] == ff[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They produce overlapping plots:

```
Plot[a[t] /. {sol, sol2, sol3, sol4} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself in the answer to this question: [Weird NDSolve behavior with Piecewise (MMA9)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/weird-ndsolve-behavior-with-piecewise-mma9)

```
NDSolve[{a'[t] == f[t]*a[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 5}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

does the trick.

Comment: Maybe you could define fTmp simply as fTmp[t_] := \[Piecewise]{{1, t <= 1}}.